# Why does this segfault?

Tags: c++, dictionary, iterator

```
for(ItemTemplateListIterator iter = item_template_list.begin(); iter != item_template_list.end(); ++iter) {
    int id = iter->first;
    string description = iter->second->description;
    some_file_stream << id << endl;
    some_file_stream << description << endl;

}
```

Where item_template_list is a `map` of `<int, MyClass*>`, `ItemTemplateListIterator` is a typedef for a `const_iterator` of `map<int, MyClass*>` and `MyClass` has a public string property called description.

Comment: Why do you store `MyClass*` instead of `MyClass`?

Comment: Why add a description in English for something that is much more precisely described with code!

Comment: It is also completely useless without the definition of MyClass and without a description of how values were inserted (and a description of why the map contains RAW pointers (who owns the object that is pointed at with these pointers (without which we can;t not determine their lifetime)))

Comment: This piece of code seems OK, maybe _segfault_ is occurred in another place!

Comment: @PC2st: Both valgrind and gdb point to that line using iter->second->description as the cause. 

@Others, I'm away from my computer ATM, I'll have more details tomorrow.

Comment: By any chance, did you stuff in address of local variables (stack variables) which are not longer valid?

Comment: Also, shouldn't id and description be reference variables, so that reading them from 'some_file_stream' updates the original entries in the map?

Comment: @chubsdad: Storing the address of stack variables was the cause. Post that as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What very likely happened is that the object pointers that you stored in the map are not valid anymore (because the memory was deallocated elsewhere). Attempting to access a deallocated memory area causes a segfault. Not valid is meaning either `NULL` or having a so-called "[dangling pointer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_pointer)".

Maybe also you are modifying the map or objects in the map in another thread while iterating through it.

There is too little code here for me to help you more.

Comment: This code is single threaded. I'll check for if it's deallocated anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

I'll take a shot.

One of the MyClass* (pointers) has a "junk" (incorrect) value when you try to access it and boo-m. Segfault city.

As commented, you can store the full object in the map and not bother with pointers.

Comment: Map has the important property that inserting a new element into a map does not invalidate iterators that point to existing elements. Erasing an element from a map also does not invalidate any iterators, except, of course, for iterators that actually point to the element that is being erased.

Answer (score 0):

one of (iter->second) == null

Answer (score 0):

The reason this is segfault is probably because the MyClass* is null or has been freed and has garbage value.

You can easily find out if it's null:

```
MyClass * obj = iter->second;
if (obj == null) {
    cerr << "Unexpected null pointer" << endl;
} else {
    string description = obj->description;
    some_file_stream << id << endl;
    some_file_stream << description << endl;
}
```

However, you still need to go through the rest of your code that populates the list and find out why it's not what you expected it to be.

Overall I'd say unless you're aiming to eliminate unnecessary copying of objects you'll be safer to store actual objects in the list and just make sure your copy constructor can handle them.